# How to print different strings depending on the input?

Tags: c, io, string-comparison

I want one message to appear if the name *Emily* or *Jack* is entered and a different message for another input.

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name;
    
    printf("What is your name?");
        
    gets(name);
    
    if ((strcmp(name,"Emily") == 0) || (strcmp(name,"Jack") == 0))
    {
        printf("Hello %s\n", name); 
    } else 
    {
        printf("Welcome Stranger!\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code will compile but won't output anything.

Comment: `name` should be an array of `char`, not just a single `char`.

Comment: Also, C is compiled.  It's not a scripting language.

Comment: Where did you learn to use `gets()`? It should never be used.

Comment: Stepping through in a debugger will likely expose the problem. Also try turning on **all compiler warnings** (e.g. `-Wall`) because this code is wildly incorrect. C will tell you, but only if asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that `name` can store exactly one `char`, to store a string of characters you'll need a `char` array.

The second problem, not causing the faulty behavior but equaly important, is the use of `gets`. This function was deprecated in **C99** and removed from the international standard with **C11**, and for good reason, it's very dangerous as it can easily overflow the destination buffer, it has no control over the length of the input stream. [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) is regularly used instead.

```
char name[256]; //array store the name

//...

fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin); //safe, can't overflow the buffer, input size is limited
name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0'; //fgets parses the newline character, it must be removed

//...
```